# Pressing enter in text box to trigger click on a button

Tags: javascript, html

I need to press enter in a text box to trigger a click event on a button. The field and button is part of a larger form that I do not want to submit with this button

Here are the codes

**Script**

```
document.getElementById('myInput').keyup=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        document.getElementById('mybtn').click();
    }
}
```

**Html**

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add "autocomplete="off"/> 
<input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onclick="retrieve('myInput');"/>
```

**Nothing happens when I press Enter**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: **Nothing happens when I press Enter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.keyup` is not a function.

To add a `keyup` event listener to an `input`, you can use `Element.onkeyup`, `Element.addEventListener("keyup", function(){})`, or add an inline `onkeyup` event handler to the element.

Generally, to add an event listener to an Element, the syntax is `Element.on[eventname]` or `Element.addEventListener("[eventname]"
, function(){})`

Using `Element.onkeyup`:

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add "autocomplete="off"/> 
<input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onClick="retrieve('myInput');"/>
<script>
document.getElementById('myInput').onkeyup=function(e){
    if(e.keyCode==13){
        document.getElementById('mybtn').click();
    }
}
function retrieve(id){
 console.log("Value: "+document.getElementById(id).value);
}
</script>
```

Adding an event listener:

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add "autocomplete="off"/> 
    <input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onClick="retrieve('myInput');"/>
    <script> 
     document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener("keypress", function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            document.getElementById('mybtn').click();
        }
});
    function retrieve(id){
     console.log("Value: "+document.getElementById(id).value);
    }
    </script>
```

Using an inline event handler:

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add "autocomplete="off" onkeyup="handleInputKeyup(event)"/> 
    <input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onClick="retrieve('myInput');"/>
    <script>
function handleInputKeyup(e){
        if(e.keyCode==13){
            document.getElementById('mybtn').click();
        }
}
function retrieve(id){
     console.log("Value: "+document.getElementById(id).value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `keyup`  with `onkeyup`

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').onkeyup = function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    document.getElementById('mybtn').click();
  }
}

function retrieve(elem) {
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add " autocomplete="off" />
<input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onclick="retrieve('myInput');" />
```

Alternately you can put the elements inside a `form` & change input type to `submit`.In that case on pressing `enter` it will trigger click event on first `submit` button inside form

```js
function retrieve(elem) {
  console.log('clicked')
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add " autocomplete="off" />
  <input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add" onclick="retrieve('myInput');" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for the keyup event of the return key (`keyCode==13`) and then dispatch the click event onto the target DOM element:

```js
document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener("keyup", function(ev){
  // console.log(ev.keyCode);
  if (ev.keyCode==13) document.getElementById('mybtn').dispatchEvent(new Event('click'));

})
```

```html
<input id="myInput" type="text" name="txt" placeholder="Enter Tag name and click Add "autocomplete="off"/> 
<input id='mybtn' class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Add" onclick="console.log('clicked, input is: '+document.getElementById('myInput').value)"/>
```

Just realised, that apart from my `.dispatchEvent()` method my approach is identical to @brk's solution. And his is shorter! I didn't know that `click()` was available in Vanilla JavaScript. I have been using jquery for so long that I don't know all these new html5/ES6 additions ;-)

However, the `.dispatchEvent` method is a universally applicable approach. You can even use it to fake the enter key being pressed on the input field by executing this little snippet::

```
var e=new Event('keyup'); e.keyCode=13;   // generate an "Enterkey pressed" event
document.getElementById('myInput').dispatchEvent(e);  // apply it on the input element
```